# Why does the mismatch sometimes occur twice before moving on?

Tags: c#, linq, combobox

I've got this code:

```
int RVHHSelectionIndex = 0;
int RVSelectionIndex = 0;
while (RVMismatch())
{
    studentFullname = checkListBoxRV.Text;
    assistantFullname = checkListBoxRVHH.Text;
    listBoxMessages.Items.Add(string.Format(mismatchDiscovered, studentFullname, assistantFullname));
    if (RVHHSelectionIndex < RVHHCount - 2)
    {
        checkListBoxRVHH.SelectedIndex = RVHHSelectionIndex++;
        checkListBoxRVHH.SetItemChecked(checkListBoxRVHH.SelectedIndex, true);
    }
    else
    {
        // If all the HHs have been gone through, start again at the beginning:
        checkListBoxRVHH.SelectedIndex = 0;
        checkListBoxRVHH.SetItemChecked(checkListBoxRVHH.SelectedIndex, true);
        // ...and move to the next Student:
        if (RVSelectionIndex < checkListBoxRV.Items.Count - 2)
        {
            checkListBoxRV.SelectedIndex = RVSelectionIndex++;
            checkListBoxRV.SetItemChecked(checkListBoxRV.SelectedIndex, true);
        }
    }
}

private bool RVMismatch()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(AYttFMConstsAndUtils.STUDENTS_FILENAME)) return true;
    if (null == AYttFMConstsAndUtils.STUDENTS_FILENAME) return true;
    int RVStudentID = Convert.ToInt32(checkListBoxRV.SelectedValue);
    int RVHHCandidateID = Convert.ToInt32(checkListBoxRVHH.SelectedValue);
    Student RVStudent = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.StudentsList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.StudentID.Equals(RVStudentID));
    Student RVHHCandidate = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.StudentsList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.StudentID.Equals(RVHHCandidateID));
    // If either are null, return true
    if ((null == RVStudent) || (null == RVHHCandidate)) return true;
    // If Student male, candidate assistant female, and not family, return true
    if (RVStudent.IsMale)
    {
        if (!RVHHCandidate.IsMale && RVStudent.FamilyID != RVHHCandidate.FamilyID) return true;
    }
    // If Student female, candidate assistant male, and not family, return true
    if (!RVStudent.IsMale)
    {
        if (RVHHCandidate.IsMale && RVStudent.FamilyID != RVHHCandidate.FamilyID) return true;
    }
    // Otherwise, it's good:
    return false;
}
```

...which is supposed to select another Householder (RVHH) when the person assigned as the main student is not a good match with that person (there are certain rules that make them a mismatch).

There are two comboboxes, one with the main student (RV) and the other with the assistant (RVHH). If the first HH is a mismatch, it moves to the next candidate HH in the combobox. If all RVHH candidates are mismatches, the RV combobox is incremented to the next, and the process starts over again until there is a match.

It works for the most part, but the odd thing is that my "log" entry sometimes shows the same mismatch being found twice. If that were *always* the case, I would figure there was an obvious and egregious flaw in my code. But it does not always occur. For example, note the "Mismatch" messages here:

[image]

For the bottom comboboxes, the first HH candidate was seen as a mismatch *twice* before moving on to the next, who was also a mismatch but only logged once, and the next, who was the same situation; it finally selected the next candidate, who was not a mismatch, and so the logging ceased.

Why was the first one gone through twice before moving on?

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: Of course; it obviously goes through the same path twice sometimes, and once other times; why, though, is the rub.

Comment: Try to provide the smallest possible code sample that any one can run individually (see also Jon Skeet's blog : http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ ). I would like to debug it, see what happens, but with the provided code, it is hard to do so...

Comment: If something happens twice, it can have multiple causes. Do your list(s) have double items? Are your conditions (checks) sometimes giving a double match? If you have a reproducible scenario, you can set breakpoints and see the state of your application (data of your list(s), each variable that is being set, you can step into checks to see why it gives a match).

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't run your code, I can't be certain; but I guess that your code runs well only on the first time the form show; and that's because when the form is first shown, the selection index of the check list boxes is always `-1` (no selection set); so there will be no problem with this bloc:

```
studentFullname = checkListBoxRV.Text;
assistantFullname = checkListBoxRVHH.Text;
listBoxMessages.Items.Add(string.Format(mismatchDiscovered, studentFullname, assistantFullname));
```

But when the code is run again, the selection index seems to have changed to `0` because of this line:

```
checkListBoxRVHH.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

So the `listBoxMessages` should read the first item twice, once before

```
if (RVHHSelectionIndex < RVHHCount - 2)
{
//...
```

And again with the normal code execution sequence.